# size of figure in slides created by Knitr

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, figure

I want to add a figure in slides by creating the beamer PDF in Rstudio with Knitr from .Rmd file, how can I control the size of the figure for figure I added with the following command?

```
   ![](plot/myfigure.png)
```

Comment: Not straightforward for now, but I'm working on this issue this week (will post an answer once it is done). You can use raw LaTeX syntax for graphics if you don't care about other types of output formats.